# How can I have text along a path with pgfplots with marks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using the `decorations.text` library to set text along a path drawn by [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). The decoration works fine without marks, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183103/32374), but with marks on the path, the compilation fails with `Package pgf Error: I cannot decorate an empty path \end{axis}`. Why, and is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
    no markers,
    decoration={
        text along path,
        text={This is my path},
    },
    postaction={decorate},
] coordinates {(0,0) (10,1)};
% \addplot+[
%     mark=*,
%     decoration={
%     text along path,
%     text={This is my path},
%     },
%     postaction={decorate},
% ] coordinates {(0,1) (10,0)}; %This one fails
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the way, for this simple example, the `sloped` option to a `node` after the `addplot` would be much simpler, but of course the real use case has a curved plot for which `sloped` isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix the problem by disabling the decoration for the marks using `mark options={decoration={name=none}}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
    no markers,
    decoration={
        text along path,
        text={This is my path},
    },
    postaction={decorate},
] coordinates {(0,0) (10,1)};
 \addplot+[
     mark=*,
     decoration={
     text along path,
     text={This is my path},
     },
     mark options={decoration={name=none}},
     postaction={decorate},
 ] coordinates {(0,1) (10,0)}; %This one fails
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the `\tikzset` line do?

Comment: @darthbith: Oops, that wasn't supposed to be there. I was thinking of a different solution at first.

Comment: OK I recognized it from Googling some other answers, but didn't remember what it did. Thanks again!