# How to typeset maths above the curve of a function with TikZ, with the curve masked (or locally opacified) to improve readibility?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, decorations

I want to label a family of curves representing a simple family of mathematical functions : x -> x²+c where c will take various values between, say, -6 and 6.

I want to superpose the label directly on the curve (thus interrupting the trace, or at least opacifying it) and let a little white space at both sides of the mathematical formula which labels each curve to help the reading.

I would also want to reduce the size of fonts inside mathematical formulas. Here where I am, with the unvaluable help of *Schrödinger's cat*, thanks to him (cf. this question [How to typeset text along the curve of a mathematical function with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511457/how-to-typeset-text-along-the-curve-of-a-mathematical-function-with-tikz), I followed his suggestion to ask a new question to improve clarity) :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing} % decoration.markings

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,>=Stealth]
            \def \xmin {-4}
            \def \xmax {4}
            \def \ymin {-6}
            \def \ymax {6}
            \draw[thin, opacity=0.2] (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax);

            \draw[very thick, ->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[below left] {$x$} ;
            \draw[very thick, ->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[below left] {$y$} ;

            \clip (\xmin, \ymin) rectangle (\xmax, \ymax) ;
            \draw[very thick, dashed, domain=-3:3,samples=200] plot (\x, {(\x)^2} ) ;
            \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \pc using {100-(\c+6)*9}, evaluate=\c as \ic using {abs(\xmax-\c)+.5}] in {-6,-4,-2,2,4} {
                \draw[very thick, domain=\xmin:\xmax,samples=200, blue!\pc!red,
                %                  text effects={path from text, characters={text along path, fill=gray!50}},
                postaction={decorate,
                    decoration={text along path,
                        raise=-.5ex,
%                        fill=green     % Let (Lua)LaTeX hang
                        text={|\scriptsize| $x {\mapsto} {x^2}+(\c)$},
                        text color=blue!\pc!red,
                        text align={align=right, right indent=\ic cm}
                    },
                    text effects={path from text, characters={text along path, fill=gray!50}},
                } ]
                plot (\x, {(\x)^2+\c} )  ;
            } ;

            \draw (0,0) node[shift={(-.3cm,-.3cm)}, fill=white, circle, inner sep=-.5pt] {$O$} ;
            \coordinate (I) at (1,0);  \draw (I) node {\small $|$} node[yshift=-.3cm, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$1$} ;
            \coordinate (J) at (0,1);  \draw (J) node {$-$} node[xshift=-.2cm, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$1$} ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried to use the TikZ library decocations.text with the "text effects along a path" decoration, but this seems to be unusable with maths...

Many thanks in advance for any ideas or improvements !

**Update**

Thanks one more time to *Schrödinger's cat*. I tweaked his idea and went to tcolorbox rather than contour. Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing} % decoration.markings

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,>=Stealth]
            \def\xmin{-4}
            \def\xmax{4}
            \def\ymin{-6}
            \def\ymax{6}
            \def\cmin{-6}
            \def\cmax{5}
            \draw[thin, opacity=0.2] (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax);

            \draw[very thick, ->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[below left] {$x$} ;
            \draw[very thick, ->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[below left] {$y$} ;

            \clip (\xmin, \ymin) rectangle (\xmax, \ymax) ;
            \draw[very thick, dashed, domain=-3:3,samples=200] plot (\x, {(\x)^2} ) ;

            \def\mycommand#1{\tcbox[size=tight, on line, colback=white, colframe=white, boxrule=0em, opacityframe=1, opacityback=0]{\tiny $#1$}}

            \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \pc using {100-(\c+6)*9}, 
                         evaluate=\c as \ic using { (\cmax-\c)^1.55 } ]
                     in {\cmin,...,-1,1,2,...,\cmax} {
                        \pgfmathsetmacro{\localxmax}{sqrt(\ymax-\c)}
                        \ifnum\c<0
                            \def\mysign{-}
                        \else
                            \def\mysign{+}
                        \fi
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\absc}{abs(\c)}
                        \draw[very thick, domain=-\localxmax:\localxmax,samples=200, blue!\pc!red,
                            postaction={decorate,
                                decoration={text effects along path,
                                    text={x{\mapsto}{x^2}\mysign\absc{\hspace{\ic em}}},
                                    raise=-.35ex,                
                                    text align={align=right}, 
                                    text effects/.cd,
                                    every character/.append style={character command=\mycommand}, text along path}
                        } ]
                        plot (\x, {(\x)^2+\c} )  ;
            } ;

            \draw (0,0) node[shift={(-.3cm,-.3cm)}, fill=white, circle, inner sep=-.5pt] {$O$} ;
            \coordinate (I) at (1,0);  \draw (I) node {\small $|$} node[yshift=-.3cm, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$1$} ;
            \coordinate (J) at (0,1);  \draw (J) node {$-$} node[xshift=-.2cm, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$1$} ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result :
[image]

One minor issue still persists : I cannot change the color of the formulas...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The technical reason why things did not work is that you should use the decoration `text effects along path` instead of `text along path`. However, at this point the story is not yet over since one wants to use math mode and somehow make the text distinguishable from the path. One possibility that came to my mind is using `contour`. All the styling of the individual characters is in

```
\def\mycommand#1{\contour{white}{$#1$}}
```

Further, since `text effects along path` do not support a right indent (while `text along path` does) I also changed the plot range. I am not claiming that contours are the best possibility but the following provides you with a working wrapper that allows you to style the texts in many ways.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing} % decoration.markings
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{0.7pt}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,>=Stealth]
            \def \xmin {-4}
            \def \xmax {4}
            \def \ymin {-6}
            \def \ymax {6}
            \draw[thin, opacity=0.2] (\xmin, \ymin) grid (\xmax, \ymax);

            \draw[very thick, ->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[below left] {$x$} ;
            \draw[very thick, ->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[below left] {$y$} ;

            \clip (\xmin, \ymin) rectangle (\xmax, \ymax) ;
            \draw[very thick, dashed, domain=-3:3,samples=200] plot (\x, {(\x)^2} ) ;
            \def\mycommand#1{\contour{white}{$#1$}}
            \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \pc using {100-(\c+6)*9}, 
                evaluate=\c as \ic using {4-\c}] in {-6,-4,-2,2,4} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\localxmax}{sqrt(6-\c)}
                \ifnum\c<0
                \def\mysign{-}
                \else
                \def\mysign{+}
                \fi
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\absc}{abs(\c)}
                \draw[very thick, domain=-\localxmax:\localxmax,samples=200, blue!\pc!red,
                %                  text effects={path from text, characters={text along path, fill=gray!50}},
                postaction={decorate,
                decoration={text effects along path,
                  text={x{\mapsto}{x^2}\mysign\absc{\hspace{\ic em}}},
                  raise=-.5ex,                
                  text align={align=right}, 
                  text effects/.cd,
                  every character/.append style={character command=\mycommand},
                , text along path}, 
                } ]
                plot (\x, {(\x)^2+\c} )  ;
            } ;

            \draw (0,0) node[shift={(-.3cm,-.3cm)}, fill=white, circle, inner sep=-.5pt] {$O$} ;
            \coordinate (I) at (1,0);  \draw (I) node {\small $|$} node[yshift=-.3cm, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$1$} ;
            \coordinate (J) at (0,1);  \draw (J) node {$-$} node[xshift=-.2cm, fill=white, inner sep=.5pt] {$1$} ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, one could just add a legend. After all, you are using different colors.

Comment: Thanks again. Your idea gave me one, that fit my needs. I will update my answer, as I don't want to make an answer by myslef that would "steal" yours...

Comment: @natsirt Thanks! Looks great!