# Writing mathematical text along a curve in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to write some mathematical text along a plotted curve in TikZ.  I have read two related questions in this site:

- [How to typeset text along the curve of a mathematical function with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511457/18)
- [Pgfplots: plot text along function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237456/18)

and have tried to follow the method in the answers, with only partial success.  Here is a minimal working example of what I am trying to do.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.text}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=1.0]
       \draw [very thick,gray,opacity=0.4] (-2.5,-2.5) -- (2.5,2.5);
       \draw [very thick,gray,opacity=0.4] (-2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,-2.5);
       \draw[line width=3pt,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,black] plot ({1.7*sinh(\x)},{1.7*cosh(\x)});  
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
   \end{document}
```

which produces this:
[image: singularity]

I would like somewhere along the thick black hyperbolic segment to write some mathematical text (e.g., r=0) aligned with the curve but not necessarily centred.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=1.0]
    \draw [very thick,gray,opacity=0.4] (-2.5,-2.5) -- (2.5,2.5);
    \draw [very thick,gray,opacity=0.4] (-2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,-2.5);
    \draw[line width=3pt,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,black,%
    postaction={decorate,%
      decoration={text along path, text={$r=0$}, raise=5pt}}%
    ] plot ({1.7*sinh(\x)},{1.7*cosh(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It produces something reasonable (although I cannot find how to position the text along the curve):

[image: singularity with text]

but I get compilation errors which I don't understand:

```
./mwe.tex:14: Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.14     ] plot ({1.7*sinh(\x)},{1.7*cosh(\x)});

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

./mwe.tex:14: Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 

l.14     ] plot ({1.7*sinh(\x)},{1.7*cosh(\x)});

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \draw [very thick,gray,opacity=0.4] (-2.5,-2.5) -- (2.5,2.5);
    \draw [very thick,gray,opacity=0.4] (-2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,-2.5);
    \draw[line width=3pt,domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\x,black,%
    postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text={$r=0$}, raise=5pt}}] plot ({1.7cm*sinh(\x)},{1.7*cosh(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}` `1.7cm*sin(\x)` solved the problem

Comment: Just reduce the samples to 11 or 15, say. The `dimension too large` errors come from Ti*k*Z wanting to compute the tangent of some very short Bezier curve segments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Dimension too large` error is in general due to the fact that by default, PGF computations rely on TeX `\dimen` registers, whose maximum value is `\maxdimen`, i.e., `16383.99999pt`, which is approximately 226.7 inches, and thus approx. 18.9 feet, hence the `19 feet` mentioned in the error message you reported.

In your case, the problem appears to be triggered by the `text along path`, *due to a particular number of samples* when drawing the curve (thanks to @Schrödinger'scat for [pointing this out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531282/writing-mathematical-text-along-a-curve-in-tikz#comment1343375_531282)). If you draw the curve with `samples=15`, it works fine.

As I understand it: a large number of samples means very short “segments” used to draw the curve (presumably, “little” Bézier curves :-). The `text along path` option probably tries to determine the slope of the segment below each box of the text to typeset, and in order to do this divides the “delta y” of a segment by its (very close to zero in this case) “delta x,” which yields a number that is too large to fit in a TeX `\dimen` register.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
\path (0,2.9);                 % extend the upper side of the bounding box

\begin{scope}[very thick, gray, opacity=0.4]
  \draw (-2.5,-2.5) -- (2.5,2.5);
  \draw (-2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,-2.5);
\end{scope}

\draw[line width=3pt, domain=-1:1, smooth, variable=\x, black,
      samples=15,   % <-------- this
      postaction={decorate,
        decoration={text along path,
                    text={$r=0$}, raise=5pt,
                    % text align={left indent=1cm},
        },
     },
     ] plot ({1.7*sinh(\x)},{1.7*cosh(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Options for positioning the text along your curve are described in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) section *Text Decorations* (around page 656). They include `align`, `left`, `right`, `center`, `left indent`, `right indent`, `fit to path` and `fit to path stretching spaces`. For instance, if you uncomment the `text align={left indent=1cm}` in my example, you'll get the r = 0 formula starting at one centimeter from the leftmost point of the curve:

[image]